# Dynamically update column value with replacement for some pattern

Tags: sql, regex, replace, sql-server-2012, sql-update

I have my table with Column MailText which has values like

```
1. <strong>abc</strong>:<description1> <strong>bcd</strong>:<description2>
2. <strong>efg</strong>:<description3> <strong>hgl</strong>:<description7>
```

Upon update I want values like

```
1. <strong>abc</strong>:<abc> <strong>bcd</strong>:<bcd>
2. <strong>efg</strong>:<efg> <strong>hgl</strong>:<hgl>
```

Please help with dynamic replacement that it would update all string within `<strong>` tag to `<description>`. `<strong>` tag may contain any values.

Comment: A good place to start: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Switched the quote formatting over to code formatting. Wasn't sure if the Numbers `1.` and `2.` are part of your record though. Please check the preview before saving your formatting. Keep in mind that adding 4 spaces before a line when editting formats the text as code. Please don't indent your non-code stuff.

Comment: As for the question itself, your desired results also switch `hgl` to `xyz`. Is that intended? If so, what's the logic there?

Comment: hello JNevill, it was mistake, hgl should be hgl.  i mean <strong>hgl</strong>: <hgl>

Comment: Please do: use the preview window to check that your HTML has appeared in your question (edited in). Please don't: add requests for urgent/preferential treatment for your questions (edited out).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE FUNCTION GetString
(
    @s NVARCHAR(MAX)
)
RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @trav                  NVARCHAR(2000) = @s,
            @length                INT,
            @count                 INT = 1,
            @startIndex            INT = 0,
            @endIndex              INT = 0,
            @replaceStartIndex     INT = 0,
            @repalceEndIndex       INT = 0,
            @replaceword           NVARCHAR(2000),
            @newWord               NVARCHAR(2000)

    SELECT @length = LEN(@Trav)
    WHILE ((@count + @startIndex) <= @length)
    BEGIN
        SET @startIndex = CHARINDEX('<strong>', @trav, @startIndex) + LEN('<strong>')
        IF (@startIndex > 8)
        BEGIN
            SET @endIndex = CHARINDEX('</strong>', @trav, @startIndex)
            SET @newWord = SUBSTRING(@trav, @startIndex, (@endIndex - @startIndex))
            SET @replaceStartIndex = CHARINDEX(':', @trav, @startIndex) + 2
            SET @repalceEndIndex = CHARINDEX('>', @trav, @replaceStartIndex)
            SET @replaceword = SUBSTRING(
                    @trav,
                    @replaceStartIndex,
                    (@repalceEndIndex - @replaceStartIndex)
                )
            --SELECT @replaceword as 'repword', @newWord as 'newword'
            SET @trav = REPLACE (@trav, @replaceword, @newWord)
            SET @count = @repalceEndIndex
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            SET @count = @count + 1
        END
    END
    RETURN @trav
END
GO


IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#table') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #table

CREATE TABLE #table
(
    string VARCHAR(1000)
)
INSERT INTO #table
SELECT 
       '1. <strong>abc</strong>:<description1> <strong>bcd</strong>:<description2>'

INSERT INTO #table
SELECT 
       '2. <strong>efg</strong>:<description3> <strong>hgl</strong>:<description7>'


UPDATE #table
SET    string = [dbo].[GetString](#table.string)

SELECT *
FROM   #table
```